# Is it efficient passing structs as parameters by value to a function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, parameters, parameter-passing

So far as I know, structs can be passed as parameter by value, or we can also pass it by reference, using pointers.

Is it efficient passing structs by value? If we have big structs with lots of fields, this does not seem to be efficient, since the struct data is copied to the formal parameters of the function, and this involves computational costs.

It seems that, in these cases, passing structs by reference is a better option. Does this make sense?

Another related question is if compilers do optimizations in this sense, converting parameter passing by value to reference.

Comment: Your initial question about if it makes sense.: Yes, I think it does. About compiler optimizations: It depends. The compiler is free to do whatever it likes just as long as the compiled version of your program behaves _as-if_ it did exactly what you wrote.

Comment: @TedLyngmo no, the compiler can't change passing by value to passing by pointer

Comment: @0___________ Why not? The whole function may even be inlined so there's no passing around of anything.

Comment: @TedLyngmo read my answe

Comment: @0___________: Presumably it could if the as-if rules aren't violated. Would only work for `static` functions though (or in link-time optimization scenarios where it can see the complete dependency graph), since anything that is visible to an unknown future caller would have to adhere to the ABI rules. Compilers would definitely do this when the function gets inlined (of course in that case, there is no real function in the resulting binary); I have no idea if they'd go to the trouble when not inlining but with adequate guarantees to maintain "as-if" behavior.

Comment: @0___________ I said _"behaves as-if it did exactly what you wrote"_ - As long as that is true, it can do whatever it likes.

Comment: @ShadowRanger it does not https://godbolt.org/z/s9nMKdqMv  https://godbolt.org/z/57qnjb4Pq

Comment: @TedLyngmo another reason is that `void x(struct foo)` and `void x(struct *foo)` are not compatible

Comment: @0___________: "Does not" is not the same as "can not". You definitely shouldn't rely on it, but it's a perfectly legal optimization to make.

Comment: @ShadowRanger can you prove it somehow? Or maybe you should add **`IMO`**

Comment: @0___________ That type information doesn't have anything to do with what happens in the assembly. If I have `void x(foo) {}` and call it, you expect a copy to be done unconditionally - but if that's not needed because the compiler knows that the function will not change anything in the passed parameter - it would be free to just reference the passed parameter and read directly from that. What rule stops it from doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a structure is small, pass it by value. Modern calling conventions provide for passing small structures in registers, on suitable platforms.

If a structure is large, you might define your routine to receive the structure by reference (using a pointer to a `const`-qualified type).

You should also declare the pointer with `restrict`, as in `const struct foo * restrict p`. Otherwise, it is possible that passing a structure by reference can impair optimization. Consider passing `const struct foo *p` to a routine that also has a parameter `struct foo *q` or `float *f`. Inside the routine, if the code changes the structure that `q` points to or the `float` that `f` points to, the compiler cannot generally know that `q` is not pointing to the same structure as `p` or that `f` is not pointing to a `float` that is a member of the structure `p` points to. This can cause the compiler to reload data from `p` multiple times when in fact no changes to `p` are occurring. Using `restrict` tells the compiler that caller will not pass a `p` such that data using via `p` will not also be used inside the routine via other points.

> Another related question is if compilers do optimizations in this sense, converting parameter passing by value to reference.

This is not common. However, returning a structure by reference is common. The calling convention is typically that the caller provides a place for the returned structure to be written to and passes a pointer to that, invisibly to the source code.

Answer (score -3):

It will not be efficient for sure, but sometimes we want to work on the local automatic variable. When you change the automatic variable it will stop to exist when the function returns and all changes will be made only to this local variable. If it is passed by a pointer then the function will modify the original object, not the local object. For this reason, the compiler will not optimize it.

```
typedef struct
{
    double x[10000];
}big_struct;

void __attribute__((noinline)) foo(big_struct bs)
{
    for(size_t i =0; i < sizeof(bs.x) / sizeof(bs.x[0]); i++) printf("%f\n", bs.x[i]);
}


void bar(void)
{
    big_struct x;

    /* some code */

    foo(x);
}
```

```
.LC0:
        .string "%f\n"
foo:
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 8
        lea     rbx, [rsp+32]
        lea     rbp, [rsp+80032]
.L2:
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 1
        add     rbx, 8
        call    printf
        cmp     rbx, rbp
        jne     .L2
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
bar:
        sub     rsp, 160008
        mov     edx, 80000
        lea     rsi, [rsp+80000]
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    memcpy
        call    foo
        add     rsp, 160008
        ret
```

Comment: @Zaratruta Not my downvote but I think it may have to do with the ongoing discussion in the comment field under the question.

Comment: @SupportUkraine answer is **correct**. Btw it works in both direction.